# json.stringify returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cassandra, ejs

I have node- express- ejs and cassandra database.
I am reading a table from cassandra in index.js file.

```
router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    client.connect(function(err) {});
    client.execute('SELECT * FROM data.test;', function(err, result) {
        var user = result.rows[2];
        console.log("here is the user", result);
        res.render('index', {
            "index": result
        });
    });
});
```

I have the log for result like below:

I am trying to pass this result to a .ejs file and get the time column from it.

//I know that using jade. we write like

//for each a in index

// a.time -> gives you each time entry

I am trying to get the same using ejs. in index.js file

```
 var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(index) %>; 
 document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML= myVar;
```

but this just outputs

**[object Object] on my UI**

Can anyone please explain how to do this in ejs??
i would like to get the time entries to a array or something but i am not understand on how to proceed with the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

If you want pass variable from jade file to index.js file, you should do something like this

**index.jade**

```
script.
  var myVar = !{JSON.stringify(index)}  
script(src='/javascripts/index.js')

div(id='pil')
```

In our case myVar will be object, so index.js should look like this

**index.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('pil').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myVar);

  // show time for first item in array 
  // document.getElementById('pil').innerHTML = myVar.rows[0].time;
};
```

We call stringify because as I said before myVar is object so we need convert it to string.

## 2

If you want just get value in jade file, you can do it like this

**index.jade**

```
div(id='pil')
  =index.rows[0].time
```

index.rows is array which contains object so you need specify index for array (in our case we specified index.rows[0]) and get field what you want for example .time.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the data object in the name of index to ejs view

```
var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(index) %>; 

alert(myVar[0].uuid)
// document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML= myVar;
```

Comment: alert('<%-index[0].uuid%'),, yes but in EJS you can parse obejct like <%-JSON.stringify(data)%  and this be in object not string

Comment: Alert does not pop up on the screen.
However I have tried saying document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML= myVar[0];

now it shows 'undefined' on the screen instead of [object Object]